# Redux Toolkit - Save dark mode value to local storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, local-storage, redux-toolkit

I'm currently learning [redux toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) and I want to store dark mode state in `localStorage` so that if the users refresh the page, selected mode stays the same. My application looks like this:

index.js

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import darkModeReducer from "./darkModeSlice";
import App from "./App";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    darkMode: darkModeReducer,
  },
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

darkModeSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  darkMode: false,
};

export const darkModeSlice = createSlice({
  name: "darkMode",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    toggleDarkMode: (state) => {
      state.darkMode = !state.darkMode;
    },
  },
});

export const { toggleDarkMode } = darkModeSlice.actions;

export default darkModeSlice.reducer;
```

What would be the optimal solution for this? Please note that I only want to store the dark mode state in local storage, so if I add other reducers in the future their values ​​won't be automatically saved there.

Comment: technically you should show us what you're thinking for a solution like `localStorage.get('isdarkmode')`.

Comment: Well, that is a problem, because I don't really have any idea for now. I know how it can be achieved when state is stored in the component with `useState`. Then we can use so called `lazy initialization` and `useEffect` to check for the local storage values but since redux has different kind of workflow, I don't really know what would be the right way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your initialState in darkModeSlice

```
const initialState = {
    darkMode: localStorage.getItem("darkMode") || false
}
```

If localstorage is undefined, it will automatically be false.
And when user changes darkMode you store it with :

```
localStorage.setItem("darkMode", darkMode);
```